# Как открыть БД созданную не мной в mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb, linux-mint

Есть папка с дампом БД. На линуксе запускаю mongodb комнадой mongo. Все успешно стартует. Дальше хочу открыть эту БД. Пишу use <путь к папке>. Не работает. Где лежат Бд созданные на моем компьютере тоже не пойму. Какую команду надо написать и куда положить ту папку с БД, чтобы запустить ее ?

Comment: Командой `mongo` вы запускаете консольный клиент. База данных запускается командой `mongod`.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно путь к папке с файлами бз указывается так:

```
mongod --dbpath /Applications/mongodb/data/db
```

Comment: Можно также положить базу в `/data/db`, если хочется запускать без параметров.

Comment: Ну вот положил в /usr/database/<имя_БД>   
запускаю монго, пишу use /usr/database/<имя_БД>   
выдает ошибку, что недопустимое имя базы данных.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, не нужно указывать путь. Нужно писать просто use <имя бд>

Answer (score 0):

Надо скачать MongoBooster ( программа для редактирования БД с графическим интерфейсом) и там уже спокойно закинуть нужную базу данных. 
В какой папке лежат БД на моем компьетере пока не понял.